# Scroll Textview with RecyclerView in like its in same scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i want to scroll textview with RecyclerView

```
 <Textview  id="info"/>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_views"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/info"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:visibility="visible" />
```

so when recycle view scroll i want textview also scroll . i tried NestedScrollView but its not working

Comment: give the height of textview hardcoded like 20dp and use this in your textview--> android:scrollbars = "vertical" and this in your java class--> yourTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

Comment: not it always at top

Comment: yes u can kept it any where that not an issue. I just told u how u can scroll your textview

Comment: i dont want it on top . i want it shld scroll when recyleview scroll

Comment: you can set that `TextView` in your RecyclerView as a row. just in `onCreateViewHolder` check the item( Ex:  if(items.get(possition) == 0) ) and change the view of Recyclerview